# Convert the string formatting

Tags: java

I am getting this string from a text file and store it to a variable like

```
File file = new File("output.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();
String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

`str` return post like this:

```
| SITENAME                     | TOTAL XML GENERATED  |     TOTAL URL ADDED IN XML      |
|:-----------------------------|:-----------:|:-----------------------------|
|https://www.google.com|71|2800884|
|https://www.google.com|71|2800884|
```

But when I am sending this `str` to api it returns `bad gateway`.

But when I am sending requested with below formatted string its accepted and posted it to messenger.

```
String str = ("| SITENAME   \t\t\t       | TOTAL XML GENERATED  | \tTOTAL URL ADDED IN XML      |\n" +
              "|:-----------------------------|:-----------:|:-----------------------------|\n" +
              "|https://www.google.com|71|2800884|\n" +
              "|https://www.google.com|71|2800884|\n" +
```

Anyone can suggest me how can i converted the string?

Comment: @zsbappa are you using windows?

Comment: i am using ubuntu

Comment: @zsbappa what about when you send it like, `String str = new String(data, "UTF-8") + "\n";`    ??

Comment: `String str = (` in an invalid syntax with a dangling `+`. Can you post the actual line that creates a working `str`?

Comment: I guess the problem is with "\r\n" and "\n". What format is your output.txt file? Unix or Dos? May be you can try `tr -d "\r"` on your input file and see whether it works.

Comment: What API accepts a string (a table?) like this as input? And a [`502 Bad Gateway`](https://httpstatuses.com/502) HTTP status code usually has nothing to do with the input.

Comment: @KDM he has said already --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746289/convert-the-string-formatting?noredirect=1#comment90452806_51746289

Comment: @snr I am asking him to check the output.txt file format. May be it is with DOS line endings.

Comment: snr your suggestion works perfectly..You can post it as a solution

Comment: @zsbappa Nice to you. Glad to hear for solving the issue! I've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought that you would work on Windows, but Ubuntu (`\n` vs `\r\n`). Later, I thought the text context could include a strange Unicode character which may mislead the code, but clean. Eventually, the latter, string keyboard-written one, has `"\n"` characters end of each line. Presumably, the passing method anticipates the character end of text as well.

```
String str = new String(data, "UTF-8") + "\n";
```

Comment: Well explained. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
   sb.append(line); //append the lines to the string
   sb.append('\n'); //append new line
}
//Required string
String newString = sb.toString();

return newString;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my string i should maintain line break and api not supported the `\r\n` and below way i just solved my problem

```
str.replaceAll("\r\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```